# Increment value over duration without setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to set a realistic countdown with numbers and a progress bar canvas animation.. This is for a turn-based card game

*Is there a way to constantly increment a value over time without setInterval?*

I've got THIS

```js
(function drawClockCanvas(){
 var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
 var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
 var cWidth=canvas.width;
 var cHeight=canvas.height;

 var countTo=31*100;

 var angle=270;
 var inc=360/countTo;
 
 var sTo, nTo, cTo; //showTimeOut newTimeOut currentTimeOut
 var pTo = new Date(); //pastTimeOut using Date, because using intervals will pause them when unfocus tab..

 function drawClock() {
  //Reset canvas
  ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,165,0,1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cWidth,cHeight);

  //Base arc
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle="#252424";
  ctx.lineWidth=14;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,100,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Dynamic arc
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle="#df8209";
  ctx.lineWidth=14;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,100,(Math.PI/180)*270,(Math.PI/180)*angle,false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Inner shadow arc
  grad=ctx.createRadialGradient(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,80,cWidth/2,cHeight/2,115);
  grad.addColorStop(0.0,'rgba(0,0,0,.4)');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5,'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
  grad.addColorStop(1.0,'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=grad;
  ctx.lineWidth=14;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,100,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Bevel arc
  grad=ctx.createLinearGradient(cWidth/2,0,cWidth/2,cHeight);
  grad.addColorStop(0.0,'#6c6f72');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5,'#252424');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=grad;
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,93,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Emboss arc
  grad=ctx.createLinearGradient(cWidth/2,0,cWidth/2,cHeight);
  grad.addColorStop(0.0,'transparent');
  grad.addColorStop(0.98,'#6c6f72');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=grad;
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,107,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Labels
  var textColor='#646464';
  var textSize="18";
  var fontFace="helvetica, arial, sans-serif";

  ctx.fillStyle=textColor;
  ctx.font=textSize+"px "+fontFace;
  ctx.fillText('TIME',cWidth/2-22,cHeight/2-45);

  //Values
  ctx.fillStyle='black';

  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
  //ctx.font = "84px arial";
  /*var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 150, 100);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 0, 128)");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(255, 153, 51)");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;*/

  ctx.font='84px '+fontFace;
  if (sTo<10) {
    ctx.fillText(sTo,cWidth/2-23,cHeight/2+28);
  } else if (sTo>100) {
    ctx.fillText(sTo,cWidth/2-69,cHeight/2+28);
  } else {
    ctx.fillText(sTo,cWidth/2-47,cHeight/2+28);
  }

  if (sTo<=0) {
   sTo=0;
   console.log("Turn Ended Out of Time");
   clearInterval(dS);
  } else {
   angle+=inc;
   nTo = new Date();
   cTo = nTo - pTo;
   sTo = Math.ceil(-cTo/1000+31);
   //console.log(sTo);
   //console.log(angle+=inc);
  }
 }

 var dS = setInterval(drawClock,10);
  
  })()
```

```css
body {
  background:#ffa500;
}
canvas {
  display:block;
  margin:20px auto;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Try to focus another Tab when running the snippet for a few seconds then return and look at the progress bar

Since setItnerval pauses if the user is focusing another tab or window, I can't track properly the time elapsed and do the animation properly. (This is *not* server side)

What I've got already is the numbers countdown using the new Date method within an interval, something like this:

Outside Interval

`var sT = new Date(); //Starting Countdown Time`

Inside Interval

`var nT = new Date(); //New Time`
`var cT = nT - sT; //Current Time`

The numbers are going just right with the Date+setInterval because when users return to the page the Inside Interval code runs immediatly updating the number tracked with Date, **the problem is the progress bar canvas animation**..

When users out-focus the page the interval stops and so do the progress bar animation

I'm a self taught person and relative new on javascript, I didn't found any related questions, maybe i'm not stating the right question. I would love to know more methods to do this!

Any kind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: This is what `requestAnimationFrame` is for.

Comment: I knew it was something easy and dumb xD thank you so much Dai will take a look

Comment: Are you sure this will not stop on tab-losing focus?

Comment: I'm afraid that requestAnimationFrame freezes when losing the window focus but thanks for pointing that out, I see it's much better to do animations with this

Comment: Note that the actual countdown continues to work, it's just the progress bar that appears to go out of sync.  This because you're dynamically calculating the new value of `sTo` based on the current time, as opposed to just incrementing the arc by a certain amount each time with `angle+=inc`. You should also work out the current angle based on time remaining/passed, rather than by incrementing. The animation won't be affected by throttled timers or missed animation frames then.

Comment: Currently the animation working successfully is very much tied to the interval specified in `setInterval` being `10` - if you calculate the angle independently, you could change this interval to whatever you want and still have it work properly.

Comment: Yes this is it! but i don't have a clue how to do this, maybe make a % of the current time then apply it to the current angle will work i think, YEAS thank you please post an answer I will give it to you

Comment: You mean calculating the angle outside the interval? but then how can i increment the angle value?

Comment: Yes, i can then change that setInterval to `1000` every second to save inecessary processing

Comment: This is harder than i thought but i will eventually get it! Please, post your answer James this is it for sure: 

I need to work out the angle with the date too, use the requestAnimationFrame to handle the animation and update it with setInterval at each second if the window loses the focus, and i'm going to eat Sushi now :D Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to James Thorpe I was able to finish this rightly, using the **current time** with decimals, working out the angle with the date maintaining the setInterval at 10, i know this can be optimized and will do!

**AWESOME THANKS!**

New result:

```js
(function drawClockCanvas(){
 var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
 var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
 var cWidth=canvas.width;
 var cHeight=canvas.height;

 var countTo=31*100;

 var angle=270;
 var inc=360/countTo;
 
 var sTo = 31, nTo, cTo;
 var pTo = new Date();

 function drawClock() {
  //Reset canvas
  ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,165,0,1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cWidth,cHeight);

  //Base arc
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle="#252424";
  ctx.lineWidth=14;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,100,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Dynamic arc
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle="#df8209";
  ctx.lineWidth=14;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,100,(Math.PI/180)*270,(Math.PI/180)*angle,false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Inner shadow arc
  grad=ctx.createRadialGradient(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,80,cWidth/2,cHeight/2,115);
  grad.addColorStop(0.0,'rgba(0,0,0,.4)');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5,'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
  grad.addColorStop(1.0,'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=grad;
  ctx.lineWidth=14;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,100,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,false);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Bevel arc
  grad=ctx.createLinearGradient(cWidth/2,0,cWidth/2,cHeight);
  grad.addColorStop(0.0,'#6c6f72');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5,'#252424');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=grad;
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,93,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Emboss arc
  grad=ctx.createLinearGradient(cWidth/2,0,cWidth/2,cHeight);
  grad.addColorStop(0.0,'transparent');
  grad.addColorStop(0.98,'#6c6f72');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=grad;
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.arc(cWidth/2,cHeight/2,107,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*360,true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  //Labels
  var textColor='#646464';
  var textSize="18";
  var fontFace="helvetica, arial, sans-serif";

  ctx.fillStyle=textColor;
  ctx.font=textSize+"px "+fontFace;
  ctx.fillText('TIME',cWidth/2-22,cHeight/2-45);

  //Values
  ctx.fillStyle='black';

  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10;

  ctx.font='84px '+fontFace;
  if (sTo<10) {
    ctx.fillText(sTo,cWidth/2-23,cHeight/2+28);
  } else if (sTo>100) {
    ctx.fillText(sTo,cWidth/2-69,cHeight/2+28);
  } else {
    ctx.fillText(sTo,cWidth/2-47,cHeight/2+28);
  }

  if (-cTo/1000+31<=0) {
   console.log("Turn Ended Out of Time");
   clearInterval(dS);
  } else {
   angle=-inc*Math.floor(-cTo/10)+270;
   nTo = new Date();
   cTo = nTo - pTo;
   sTo = Math.floor(-cTo/1000+31);
   //console.log(-cTo/1000+value);
   //console.log(sTo);
  };
  if (sTo < 0) { sTo=0; };
 }

 dS = setInterval(drawClock, 10);
  
  })()
```

```css
body {
  background:#ffa500;
}
canvas {
  display:block;
  margin:20px auto;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```